# Why am I not seeing the massive performance difference that I expect to see between prepared and non-prepared queries?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I thought I would have seen a noticeable performance difference between the use of a **PDO statement** and a **PDO query** when looping over a thousand records one-by-one.

I made the loop a thousand times for each of those, to get average results and they both reflect pretty much the same time (≈0.105 seconds). Why? I would have thought the prepared statement to be the fastest.

Here is the code I used for testing purposes:

```
$iter = 1000;
$idAry = range(1,1000);
$sumResultAry = array();

// [TEST1]
$func1 = function($id,array &$sumResultAry){
    list($dbCon,$DB,$TP) = AClass::retrieve_database_properties_();
    $sql = "
        SELECT 
            t1.id,
            t1.look_key
        FROM {$DB}.{$TP}test t1 
        WHERE 
            t1.id={$id} 
    ";

    if(false!==($result=$dbCon->query($sql))){
        if(false!==($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
            $sumResultAry[] = $row['id'];
        }
    }
};

$wh = fopen('test','w');
if($wh){
    for($i=0;$i<$iter;++$i){
        $startTime = microtime(true);
        foreach($idAry as $id){
            $func1($id,$sumResultAry);
        }
        $endTime = number_format((microtime(true)-$startTime),4);
        fwrite($wh,$endTime . "\n");
    }

    fclose($wh);
}

$result = 0;

$rh = fopen('test','r');
if($rh){
    while(!feof($rh)){
        $line = trim(fgets($rh));
        if($line!==''){
            $result += floatval($line);
        }
    }

    fclose($rh);
}

echo '<pre>';
echo 'test query' . "\n\n";
echo 'time: ' . ($result/$iter) . ' seconds' . "\n\n";
echo '</pre>';
// [/TEST1]

// [TEST2]
$func2 = function($id,array &$sumResultAry){
    $key = 'test';
    $sqlStmt = null;
    if(null===($sqlStmt=AClass::return_sqlStatement_($key))){// retrieving statement if previously stored
        list($dbCon,$DB,$TP) = AClass::retrieve_database_properties_();
        $sql = "
            SELECT 
                t1.id,
                t1.look_key
            FROM {$DB}.{$TP}test t1 
            WHERE 
                t1.id=:id
        ";
        if(AClass::prepare_sqlStatement_($key,$sql)){// preparing and storing statement
            $sqlStmt = AClass::return_sqlStatement_($key);
        }
    }
    if(null!==$sqlStmt){
        if(false!==($sqlStmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id)))){
            if(false!==($row=$sqlStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
                $sumResultAry[] = $row['id'];
            }
        }
    }
};

$wh = fopen('test','w');
if($wh){
    for($i=0;$i<$iter;++$i){
        $startTime = microtime(true);
        foreach($idAry as $id){
            $func2($id,$sumResultAry);
        }
        $endTime = number_format((microtime(true)-$startTime),4);
        fwrite($wh,$endTime . "\n");
    }

    fclose($wh);
}

$result = 0;

$rh = fopen('test','r');
if($rh){
    while(!feof($rh)){
        $line = trim(fgets($rh));
        if($line!==''){
            $result += floatval($line);
        }
    }

    fclose($rh);
}

echo '<pre>';
echo 'test statement' . "\n\n";
echo 'time: ' . ($result/$iter) . ' seconds' . "\n\n";
echo '</pre>';
// [/TEST2]
```

---

Thanks to some of you, I now understand that I need to test with more complex queries to notice a significant performance difference between the two.

Comment: Per the great manual in the sky. "By using a prepared statement the application avoids repeating the analyze/compile/optimize cycle." http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php  You're query is very simple so 1000 iterations of the analyze/compile/optimize cycle is negligible. Try a more complex query. (Add dependent sub-queries and etc.  )

Comment: @brassxzero Oh I see! So with a more complexe query I WOULD SEE a difference. I'll test further just to verify this I guess. I know these things have probably been tested a thousand times, but I just added a class that stores the prepared statements used through out my project and wanted to see if I was doing this the good way so I started testing it out. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @bassxzero  I've always referred to the process of running the analyze/compile/optimize cycle as 'determining the execution plan'.  In mysql  (assuming mysql or postgres) is this accurate proper language?

Comment: This is totally unclear.

Comment: @4n0nym0u5  I'd restructure your post to ask a clear question, like 'why am I not seeing the massive performance difference between prepared and non-prepared queries'  I think folks are downvoting you because there's not an explicit question in your post

Comment: Just a note for those giving a negative score to my question. First question here and did put efforts to search through php docs and through stackoverflow. Haven't seen any mention of simple query vs complexe query to notice the performance difference between the two anywhere... But eh... Answers I got were useful anyway so I guess score doesn't really matter that much. Peace.

Comment: @Ray Thank you I'll take note of that.

Comment: What is it that you are asking? You don't have an explicit or even implicit question anywhere that i can see. Are you asking why prepared statements aren't faster?

Comment: Changed the title of my post as suggested by @Ray

Comment: @Ray I would refer to it as 'determining the execution plan' in Oracle SQL, but i'm honestly not sure what to call it for MySQL. For lack of a better term I would probably call it that for MySQL as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any case, I'm not sure you'll see 'massive' performance differences unless you're running very many iterations.

Creating a prepared statement and submitting it with a set of parameters will take slightly more time than a static query (for a single query and set of parameters) for a single run of a query.   By slightly, we're talking  ballpark of milliseconds or fractions of milliseconds.

What you do get from prepared statements (if your database supports them) is:

- SQL injection protection
- Speedup when running the same query multiple times with different parameters (like in a loop) as the database only creates one execution plan.  Typically you'd need to run quite a few executions to see anything noticeable.

If it's a quick, well-indexed query that itself takes only a few milliseconds to run, and has a trivial execution plan to build, you may need to run many thousands of requests to get any noticeable improvement with prepared statements over a static query.

So, just use prepared statements because it's better in general.

Comment: @Ray I understand that this is the case for a single request. But what about multiple requests?

Comment: @MarkBaker see my update

Comment: @4n0nym0u5 see my update.  For repetitive requests on the same statement after a few requests you should see some improvement vs. running a  static query again and again with different values

Comment: @Ray I knew about the facts you put in your answer, but my simple test was not reflecting these and I wondered why... But with the answer bassxzero gave me as a comment to my question, now I see that I need to put up a more complexe query to notice the performance difference between the two. I will still accept your answer, thank you.

Comment: @4n0nym0u5  I had added info at the bottom of my answer which reflects pretty much what bassxzero notes in a comment to your OP about the time it takes mysql to construct an execution plan (the analyze/compile/optimize  cycle constructs the execution plan)

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I not seeing the massive performance difference that I expect to see between prepared and non-prepared queries?

Because there isn't.

I don't know where did you get that idea, but nowhere a prepared statement gives you even significant performance difference, let alone a "massive" one. *Even if used properly*.

Comment: So... Just to know what you think... Is it a good practice to use prepared statement whenever it's possible? Should they be stored if reused through different classes and methods? Thank you

Comment: A good question. I think the gain doesn't worth the trouble. It will make your code A LOT more complicated with little to none gain. Besides, there is very little chance to reuse a prepared statment in PHP.

Comment: By the way I'll give a thorough read of your PDO tutorials. The use of PDO is still a bit new for me, was used to mysqli, but I do prefer PDO for their placeholders.

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to ask if you happen to have any questions